# How to read <table> into 'onmouseover' event with C# and HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How to read `<table>` into `onmouseover` event with C# and [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)?

markup code :

```
<a href="#" class="chan_live_not_free" onclick="return false;" onmouseover="return overlib('
    <table>
        <tr class=fieldRow>
            <td class=posH_col width=40>
                <strong>pos</strong>
            </td>
            <td class=rest_col width=90>
                <strong>satellite</strong>
            </td>
            <td class=freqH_col width=50>
                <strong>freq</strong>
            </td>
            <td class=rest_col width=90>
                <strong>symbol</strong>
            </td>
            <td class=rest_col width=90>
                <strong>encryption</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=&quot;pos_col&quot;>39.0&deg;e</td>
            <td class=rest_col>Hellas Sat 2</td>
            <td class=&quot;freq_col&quot;>12.606 H</td>
            <td class=rest_col>30000 - 2/3</td>
            <td class=enc_not_live>MPEG-4 BulCrypt</td>
        </tr>
    </table>',CAPTION, 'Arena Sport 4 (serbia) &nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;19/10/14 - 11:30');" onmouseout="return nd();">
    Arena Sport 4 (serbia)
</a>
```

I need to read the table into `onmouseover` event. How does it read?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "read table into 'onmouseover' event"? Post some codes showing your attempt, output you get using that code, and the output you expect to get.. that will make the question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the element attribute of the `<a>` tag with HTML Agility Pack and then using regular expressions get the `<table>` inside the string, something like the following code :

```
var html = @"<a href='#' class='chan_live_not_free' onclick='return false;' onmouseover='return overlib(
                    <table>
                        <tr class=fieldRow>
                            <td class=posH_col width=40>
                                <strong>pos</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class=rest_col width=90>
                                <strong>satellite</strong>
                            .
                            .
                            .

                        <tr>
                            <td class=&quot;pos_col&quot;>39.0&deg;e</td>
                            <td class=rest_col>Hellas Sat 2</td>
                            <td class=&quot;freq_col&quot;>12.606 H</td>
                            <td class=rest_col>30000 - 2/3</td>
                            <td class=enc_not_live>MPEG-4 BulCrypt</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>,CAPTION, 'Arena Sport 4 (serbia) &nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;19/10/14 - 11:30');' onmouseout='return nd();'>
                    Arena Sport 4 (serbia)
                </a>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='chan_live_not_free']").Attributes["onmouseover"].Value;

var text = Regex.Matches(value, @"<table>([^)]*)</table>")[0].Value;
```